# Check if websocket server started using php

Tags: php, sockets, websocket

I have created simple chat using websockets in PHP. I run it in hosting by using nohub like this

```
nohup /usr/local/bin/php5 /.../../file.php </dev/null 2>
```

I would like to put a simple script to cronjob for checking your `file.php` is up or not if its not run it again. But how I will check using server is up or down I don't know. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could use Supervisor to do this.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps
It will monitor the service running, that it started, and if the service goes down it will start it again.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: how can i make this post it as solved?

Comment: Somebody needs to post an answer and you can select that answer as best answer.